# What is the meaning of "broadcast" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "broadcast" here?
"Getting into the consumer's head involves thinking about our long-inculcated awareness of the broadcast and the private.The most important part of a message (the bit we notice first) is often not the content, but the intended audience".
https://econsultancy.com/blog/67464-why-email-is-the-king-of-one-to-one-marketing

As far as I get, it is set against the noun "private" which is "private information". Google and the Free dictionary didn't help. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/broadcast

Comment: Broadcast here is the past tense of the verb Broadcast, in this case meaning '[the things which were] broadcast', i.e. things which were made publically available versus 'the private', things which were kept private.

Comment: Yeah, it pretty much just means "public" in this context.

Comment: Understand that originally "broadcast" referred to taking a handful of seed and "casting it broadly about" to sow it into a field.  In effect the above quote is discussing where the hand is throwing the seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The broadcast* and *the private* are being used to label groups - broadcast messages and private messages - in the same way that we use *the old* or *the unemployed*.

Your quoted sentence basically says that we are aware of these groups, and the first thing we notice is which group a message belongs in, before we even see the content. The next (unquoted) paragraph gives an example of how this awareness of the groups influences expectations: a message from the CEO in the brodcast group could be big news, while a message from the CEO in the private group could be a big opportunity.